# The space of all constructions of $(\infty, 1)$-categories

Tags: lo.logic, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

In the paper *[How to glue derived categories](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13373-018-0119-z)* the following is written about $(\infty, 1)$-categories:

> This idea was discussed quite a lot in the early 1990-ies, and probably before that,
> but people were reluctant to try to turn it into actual mathematics. Here is a rough
> summary explaining why:
>
> (i) It was felt that it certainly can be done, and in several ways.
>
> (ii) All of the constructions would be very complicated and ad hoc. There is no
> preferred construction.
>
> (iii) This would not matter: all of the constructions will be equivalent, and moreover,
> “the space of all possible constructions is contractible”.
>
> (iv) Moreover, one could even turn the last statement into a theorem.
>
> (v) However, to do so, one needs to make sense of “the space of all constructions”.
> This is certainly possible, and there are several ways to do it, just as in (i). But
> then one also has (ii), (iii), (iv), (v), and the infinite loop.

Have there been efforts to make precise the points (iv) and (v)? There is a paper of Toën titled "Vers une axiomatisation de la théorie des catégories supérieures" but I don't know anything besides that.

Comment: There is the work of Barwick--Schommer-Pries: https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.0040

Comment: @OP, have you read the paragraph that follows the text you have quoted? There are a *lot* of pointers. Anyway you might also be interested in Bergner's *The homotopy theory of $(\infty, 1)$-categories* which is kind of a survey of the whole thing.

Comment: The fact that $\infty$-groupoid of automorphisms of the category of $\infty$-category is understood (and very simple: it is the discrete group corresponding to taking opposite categories at various level) is I think the best to this question: it shows that up to confusion between a category and its opposite there is always a unique way to identifies two given models.